# How to decalare a new datasource in jboss as 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

As I know with the new JBoss application server, there is 2 ways to declare datasources :

- Adding the datasource to the standalone.xml file
- Adding the datasource under application.ear/META-INF/datasource-**ds**.xml

My questions are :

1. what is the best way to declare datasources in term of (best practices/maintainability,.. )
2. If I use the 2sd way, does my datasource shared between all ear deployed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The best way (and safest) to add a datasource is by means of adding at first a new module for the JDBC driver, then creating a datasource which uses the JDBC driver as a module. See here [how to create a datasource with JBoss AS 7](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-datasource/how-to-configure-a-datasource-with-jboss-7) 
Deploying a datasource along with your application should be used for test purposes only as it is won't be manageable from the AS 7 Console/CLI this way.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply, but I don't need to install a new module for my driver, if the datasource has been configured in standalone.xml, I have just to add the driver jar to the deployments folder and the application server will recognize it